# Adding to the head in a doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have the following:

```
typedef struct value value;

struct value{
  value* prev;
  value* next;
  int value;
};

...
//ent = entry
if(entry_head == NULL) { 
 entry_head = ent;
 entry_tail = ent;
 entry_tail->prev = NULL;
}
else { // add to top
 entry_head = ent
 entry_tail = entry_tail->next;
}
```

When I insert some values into the list, I get the following outcome.

```
Expected: b         Result: a
          a                 b
```

How do I modify it so that newly added nodes are linked to the top of the previous ones?

Comment: i think you should show some more code, that says wat these variables are..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't setting enough pointers.  In general, you must ensure that the new node's `prev` is correct; that it's `next` is correct; that the previous entry's `next` is correct; and that the next entry's `prev` is correct (being careful if either the previous or next entry is NULL).

Assuming that the global variables are:

```
value *entry_head = NULL;
value *entry_tail = NULL;
```

then the code to insert a new `value *ent` (already initialized with a value) is:

```
if (entry_head == NULL)
{
    assert(entry_tail == NULL);
    entry_head = ent;
    entry_tail = ent;
    ent->next = NULL;
    ent->prev = NULL;
}
else
{
    assert(entry_tail != NULL);
    ent->next = entry_head;
    ent->prev = NULL;
    entry_head->prev = ent;
    entry_head = ent;
}
```

Analogous code can be used to insert at the tail of the list, and slightly different code inserts either before or after an existing entry in the list.